# Django rest framework posting expects dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post to my API with foreign key relationships.  It's throwing me back an error saying it's expecting a dictionary as opposed to int for `character`, `character_opponent` and `stage`.  This is because the way my models are set up.  They have foreign key relationships.  The model in question looks like this:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from analysis.models import Analysis
from characters.models import Character
from stages.models import Stage

class Match(models.Model):
    analysis = models.ForeignKey(Analysis, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    character = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='character')
    character_won = models.BooleanField()
    character_opponent = models.ForeignKey(Character, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='character_opponent')
    character_opponent_won = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self): 
        return '%s vs. %s on %s' % (self.character, self.character_opponent, self.stage)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' On save, update timestamps '''
        if not self.created_at:
            self.created_at = timezone.now()
        self.updated_at = timezone.now()
        return super(Match, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "matches"
```

And here is my serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from matches.models import Match
from characters.serializers import CharacterSerializer
from stages.serializers import StageSerializer

class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    character = CharacterSerializer()
    character_opponent = CharacterSerializer()
    stage = StageSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ('id', 'analysis', 'character', 'character_won', 'character_opponent', 'character_opponent_won', 'stage')
```

Is there some option I am missing here to be able to post properly?  Clearly I shouldn't have to pass the entire character object each time I want to post something, right?  I should just be able to pass the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your few comments I understood that you need nested serializer in `GET` method. What I suggest is, use two[or more] serializers for your API class.
Assuming you are using `ModelViewSet` API class is using,then you could override `get_serializer_class()` method as below,

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet


class MatchAPI(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Match.objects.all()

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'create':
            return MatchCreateSerializer
        return MatchSerializer
```

And your `MatchCreateSerializer` will be like this,

```
class MatchCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Match
```

Thus, you only need to provide the `PKs` of `analysis`,`character` etc while creation of `Match` instance

Comment: Thanks!  I made two serializers, one called `MatchReadSerializer` and `MatchCreateSerializer` and used them in their proper settings.  All is well now and I can post to them!

Answer (score 1):

It will come down to your CharacterSerializer and StageSerializer. If you want to input 1 format (using `serialisers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`), but output another (`CharacterSerializer`, `StageSerializer`), you might be best served using 2 serialisers and switching in your view.

In your view you can override `get_serializer_class` and check your request method, or in the case of a viewset you can check the method being invoked.

Comment: You're saying use a serializer for `GET` and another for `POST`?  Seems kind of weird...

Comment: I agree it's a little odd on the surface. The idea is that you've got 2 different representations of the same object - so 2 different serialisers. Alternatively you could create a custom field type that inherits `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and override the to_representation method to change the output.

Comment: Example at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a serializer related field using another serializer, like this

```
character = CharacterSerializer()
```

you are telling django-rest-framework that you want a nested serializer.  What you want is something like this instead

```
character = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
```

or you can actually just leave the explicit field declaration out of the serializer (since this is the default), see [the doc on serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me because I need the nested field when I use `GET`.

Comment: If you need the deserializer to work differently than the serializer, then you should go with Jason Havenaar's suggestion to use two serializers.  I was just responding to your question about how to get the primary key to work.